# Appropriate to list personal photography website on resume?

Tags: resume, websites

I'm a recent graduate looking for entry level positions relating to front-end web development.

I maintain a personal website for my photography, and I was wondering if it would be appropriate to list that on my resume under the Projects heading?

It is worth noting that this on a sub-domain of my portfolio website.

Comment: Are you really asking this question? Isn't a portfolio expected of a design job?

Comment: The important question here: do you want to add it because the *custom* design and layout of that website is (objectively) very good and speaks to your sense of UX and design, or because of the photographs?

Answer (score 8):

If you feel your photography skills are applicable to the job you are applying for (either directly it if it involves photography, or indirectly if it involves showing that you have a sense of visual design) then **sure, add it**.

Comment: And if they're not: **don't.**

Comment: Or alternately: if the job you are applying for **does** require it, add it under the projects/skills etc section. Otherwise add it under a supporting information, hobbies, "additional skills" or similar heading. A resume isn't *just* about highlighting relevant skills, it's also about highlighting an interest in the general domain you are working in... just make sure things are in the right section, so the recruiter can look at them or skip over them, depending on their priorities, time pressure and inclination.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for front-end development work, and you have a website that you developed. Why wouldn't you list that on your resume?

The content is immaterial - the work in presenting that front-end is entirely relevant to the skills you need to demonstrate for your prospective role.

Comment: I think that if the OP clicked on a bunch of photos in Lightroom and had it generate a Flash gallery that he uploaded, they shouldn't mention it.  If they designed the page on their own and wrote the HTML, CSS, JS, etc, then of course it should be used.